# Satisfiability of at least k linear equations over Z2 is NP-hard

Tags: np-complete, reductions, satisfiability

Given a system of $m$ equations in $n$ boolean variables:

$$\begin{align}
a_{11}x_1 + a_{12}x_2 + \dots +a_{1n}x_n &= b_1\pmod2\\
a_{21}x_1 + a_{22}x_2 + \dots +a_{2n}x_n &= b_2\pmod2\\
&\;\vdots\\
a_{m1}{x_1} + a_{m2}x_2 + \dots +a_{mn}x_n &= b_m\pmod2
\end{align}$$

Where all $a_{ij}, x_i$ and $b_i$ are $0$ or $1$, I want to prove that the decision problem of finding if there is a vector $x$ that satisfies at least $k$ equation, is NP hard.

I was given a hint to reduce from 3-SAT, so I am trying to build from each clause in the 3-SAT formula several equations, such that **a constant number** of them is satisfied iff the clause is satisfied. But I am not sure how to impose this restriction of a constant number of equations satisfied (for all different truth assignments that satisfy the given clause).

Comment: Make sure that when the clause is _not_ satisfied, _fewer than_ that constant number of equations are satisfied. ​ ​

Comment: But I am trying to prevent a situation where k equations are sastified, but none of them represents the satisfaction of a specific clause, hence the entire boolean formula is actually not satisfied. As far as I understand, to ensure that I must make sure that a constant number of equations is satisfied iff the clause is satisfied, not "more than k for some k". Am I wrong?

Comment: I apparently mis-interpreted your question ​ - ​ I thought what you weren't sure about was why a [gadget](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/9173/6973) with specified properties sufficed, rather than how to get such a [gadget](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/9173/6973). ​ ​ ​ ​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider any clause $x \lor y \lor z$, and the following table:
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
\text{satisfied literals} & [x]+[y]+[z] & [x\oplus y] + [x\oplus z] + [y\oplus z] & [x\oplus y\oplus z] \\\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\hline
1 & 1 & 2 & 1 \\\hline
2 & 2 & 2 & 0 \\\hline
3 & 3 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
$$
Here $[x]$ is 1 if $x$ is satisfied and 0 otherwise.

The first row sums to 0, and the rest sum to 4 (ignoring the column labeled "satisfied literals"). Can you use this to your advantage?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sorry for my ignorance, but what does ⊕ mean?

Comment: It stands for XOR.

Comment: I think I understand;is it right to say that [x]+[y]+[z] corresponds to the three equations 1*x = 1, 1*y=1, 1*z=1, and [x⊕z] (for example) corresponds to 1*x + 0*y + 1*z = 1?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you please share in brief the intuition that led you to this answer?

Comment: I might have seen this gadget before, or at least something similar. The more you practice, the easier it will be to come up with these reductions.